# Eclipse plugin Development - Is it possible to add a new option in right-click-on-method menu?

Tags: eclipse, plugins

I´m currently developing an Eclipse plugin for my research and my professor wants me to add a new option in the menu that appears when you right-click a method in the editor... something like showing runtime exceptions which can appear in method execution... anyone knows if it´s possible to add a new menu option for this in Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `org.eclipse.ui.menus` extension point to do this: http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fworkbench_cmd_menus.htm and http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fextension-points%2Forg_eclipse_ui_menus.html

Comment: any tutorials about how to use them?